# how to get data from two table which has no relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I have the following tables:

- `patient_medicines` (`id`, `drugname`, `strength`, `state`, `quantity`, `active`, `patient_id`)
- `medicine_products` (`id`, `prod_name`, `prod_generic`, `prod_state`, `prod_strength`, `prod_company`,  `batchno`, `rate`,
  `quantity`, `prod_expired`)
- `stocks` (`id`, `medicine_product_id`, `batchno`, `rate`, `quantity`, `discount`, `date`)

since there is no association of relation between `patient_medicines` and `medicine_products` table, i want to get all the patient drugname from the
patient_medicines and show the availaible quantity by subtracting the `stocks.quantity - patient_medicines.quantity as availablenow` [in `stocks`]
if the `patient_medicines` is not in the `product_medicines` table then show "not_available_in_stock"

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Isn't `drugname` the relationship between the two tables?

Comment: #Barmar , yes they are the same

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Eveyone thank you for your time**
i solved it by lef joining the patient_medicines and product based on their name and state

Answer (score 0):

There does appear to be a relationship between the two tables, for example:

WHERE patient_medicines.drugname = medicine_products.prod_name
OR patient_medicines.drugname = medicine_products.prod_generic

But I'm not sure what good it does to subtract the prescribed quantity for a single patient from the overall stock.

Comment: that do work but  only if the medicine is in the products table. I am in the need of showing all the patients drugname even if does not exist in the products table

Comment: If you have mulitple batches of a single medicine in stock, do you need to sum their quantities before doing the subtraction? Also, does the query have to handle the possible substitution of a generic for a brand, or a brand for a generic?